# Одинаковые отступы на разных устройствах

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Как сделать одинаковые отступы на разных устройствах android ? к примеру если на `nexus 10` делаю отступ в `300 dp` то смотрится хорошо, а если делаю тот же отступ на другом устройстве, к примеру на `nexus 5` то элемент отображается не так как надо(становиться слишком мелким)

Comment: Вычислите отступ исходя из размеров экрана.

Comment: Какие отступы и что значит одинаковые? Одинаковые пропорции?